# How to say in short and unequivocally in English: "I am preparing for a trip but I am still at home"?

Tags: sentence-construction, verbs

I think I should make myself as clear as possible. I hate ambiguities so much! I am however sorry for my poor vocabulary (7,000 words).

Imagine someone calling you. The caller obviously does not know where you are (he/she doesn't see you), but he/she wants to know what you are doing. You are at home at the moment, and you **are preparing** for a trip. Imagine you wish to go to a museum. However, **the trip hasn't started yet**. You are still at home.
The question is, how to respond properly?

> 1. I am going to go to (a/the) museum.

This first sentence is ungrammatical because I've heard plenty of times it's wrong. My textbooks also say very clearly that one must not use "going to" before motion verbs such as: [to] go, [to] come, [to] move, [to] walk et cetera.

> 2. I am going to a/the museum.

This second sentence is in Present Progressive, or Present Continuous. The caller would understand it as I am already on my road while I am certainly not. As I've stated  before, my trip hasn't started yet; I am only making my preparations.

So how will you respond if you **want to avoid any ambiguities**, does the English even give you such a possibility? I'm very curious!

Comment: "I am going to go to (a/the) museum." - there is _nothing wrong_ with this sentence.

Comment: "My textbooks also say very clearly that one must not use "going to" before motion verbs such as: [to] go, [to] come, [to] move, [to] walk et cetera." Your textbooks are either wrong, or you are misreading them.

Comment: "I'm about to leave for the museum" could be a reason for making the call a short one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on the false premise that utterances like ***I'm going to go home now*** are somehow syntactically and/or idiomatically "invalid".

Comment: It's true that the infinitive "to go" is often replaced with the continuous form "*We're going to the mountains*" but keeping "to go" in "*We're **going to go to** the mountains*" is never "wrong".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

True ambiguity is where the meaning of what you said, although grammatically correct, is not clear. Omitting information, either purposefully or without intention, is not necessarily ambiguity.

Saying "I'm **still** at home" implies that you are intending to go somewhere. That might be adequate to let someone know where you are, but that you are leaving shortly. Sure, it omits information about where you are going, but there's nothing ambiguous about it.

Likewise "I'm **preparing** to go out" implies that you have not yet gone out. Preparation comes before the action. It omits your current location, but again, it isn't ambiguous if all you want to say is what you are doing, and that it will result in you leaving soon.

Neither of your numbered suggestions implies any preparation is currently taking place - they just state your destination. The difference is that "I'm going to a museum" could imply that you are already on your way (assuming your listener doesn't know your location and that doesn't inform them otherwise), so in a way this does have some ambiguity. "I'm going to go..." does make it clear that you have not yet left.